# How to remove particular harmonics in time series?

Tags: r, time-series, fft, dft, spectrum

I have a time series with hourly (moving average) data from 2014 to 2019.

I used the `fft()` function to find the harmonics, and `quantmod::findPeaks()` to find the positions of the highest valued ones, which gave me as result the following positions: `8 56 2193 4384 6575 8766 306737 308928 311119 313310 315447 315495` (there are 315499 elements in the time series).

Now I need to transform this back to the time domain, but substituting zero for the value of the data in those positions. How can I do that?

Also, I noticed that when I plotted the `fft()` function (the absolute values of the FFT), the x-axis was still showing the years 2014 to 2019. Shouldn't it turn into Hz axis (frequency)?

z is my time series

```
FFT <- fft(z)
FFT <- abs(FFT/FFT[1])
plot(FFT)

PK <- findPeaks(FFT, thresh = T)
PK
```

The results of `PK` are the 12 peaks I mentioned, representing the highest harmonic distortions.
I need to remove those. I believe I can simply do `FFT[8]=0` to the 12 peaks, but I'm not sure. (I tried that, but it won't let me reverse back to time domain)

I also need to prove that the resulting FFT plot is really the Fourier spectrum, but the x-axis is not frequency. Any idea on how to make that correction?

Comment: can you show us a [mcve] please?  Note that `zz <- Re(fft(fft(z),inverse=TRUE))/length(z)` gives a result that is equal to the original `z` ...

Comment: Thank you, Ben,
The code is correct, thanks, I just need to remove harmonics first.
I edited the question to include the example.

Comment: what package is the `findPeaks()` function from? `quantmod`? (I don't think it's part of base R)

Comment: Yes, it is from `quantmod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulated square wave + (low) noise

```
set.seed(101)
ncycles <- 20
len <- 50
z <- rep(rep(0:1,each=len),ncycles) + rnorm(len*ncycles,mean=0, sd=0.02)
plot(z,type="l")
```

FFT and find peaks

```
f <- fft(z)
F <- abs(f/f[1])
PK <- quantmod::findPeaks(F,thresh=0.01)
```

Plot sqrt(power spectrum):

```
plot(F,type="l")
abline(v=PK,col=2)
```

Zero out peaks:

```
fz <- f
## position of 'peaks' is actually *one before* PK (not sure why?)
fz[PK-1] <- 0
```

Inverse transform, compare with original:

```
zz <- Re(fft(fz,inverse=TRUE))/length(f)
plot(z,type="l")
lines(zz,type="l",col=2)
```

Comment: In the power spectrum, the x axis is still as "Time", is there any way to convert it to frequency? I mean, it is frequency domain, right? So it shouldn't be time in the x axis.

Comment: I suspect you're making your data into a time series, which isn't necessary.  If you want to un-time-series it, you can use `c()`